# How to create LAN among machines on internet

Tags: vpn, lan

Say i have home PC and office PC (both Windows 7) having internet connections. How to bring them together on a LAN ?

Another is if there is an existing LAN, then how to join these PCs to that LAN ?

VPN ? If yes, How to identify each machine, which IP to use ? and How to determine if they are on same LAN ?

Basically i want to use the machines for a distributed cloud application.

I installed hamachi on 2 machines and made them join network in mesh mode , but now how to communicate among them (via HTTP URLs) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have a VPN (Hamachi) configured, so all you need is to type `http://5.x.y.z/` in your browser - and there's your URL. (`5.x.y.z` is the address Hamachi assigns. It should be shown in the Hamachi client, and in Network control panel.)

Comment: i tried it . it says url not found or something.

Comment: @Munish: "or something" is not enough. If you get an error message, please post it in its entirety.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you mean by "communicate via http url" !

Just consider this: all the machine belonging to the same group behave, through internet, the same as on a local network.

If you want to share files, enable samba on each pc. If you want to transfer by FTP, install an FTP server on a machine and a client on the other. If you have a personal web server on pc1 which hamachi adress is 5.xxx, others members of this group can reach it at http://5.xxx

In case you want them added to an existing "hamachi lan" (not the proper term), login to your  hamachi web account at http://logmein.com, find a group and note the group ID. Then go back to your hamachi UI interface, click network/join network, type this ID and matching password.
Do it for each client. You should see the list of new members in your account.